# Can a recursive function in curried form be tail recursive?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion, currying

Given is the following recursive `map` function:

```js
const U = f => f(f);
    
const map = f => U(h => acc => ([head, ...tail]) => head === undefined
 ? acc
 : h(h)([...acc, f(head)])(tail))([]);
    
const xs = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(map(x => x * x)([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Obviously, the recursive call `h(h)` isn't the last action of the recursive function. But when the stack is unwound, everything that happens is that the finished accumulator is returned without any further changes or operations. Is `map` against my expectations tail recursive?

Comment: I think this is a confused `map` implementation. It mixes `map` and `reduce` together in one procedure. I'm sharing [gist: u.js, y.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ccdd17b0b16f75bc38af2930ca6655f) to show that two separate procedures help the readability of `map`. I also did an implementation using `Y` to show how the two implementations compare. You probably know this, but the only difference with `Y` really is that you just apply `h` instead of `h (h)`. Oh and yes, tail calls throughout. Now we're just waiting on an engine that implements tail call elimination ...

Comment: Thanks @naomik, I absolutely agree with you. This was just a challenge how `map` can be implemented without deriving it from `reduce`. I had no intention to publish this, until the curried application in tail position baffled me.

Comment: No problem **＾＿＾**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the recursive call `h(h)` isn't the last action of the recursive function

`h(h)` is not a recursive call. The `…(tail)` is the recursive call, and yes, it's in a tail position.

This might get more obvious if you drop that overcomplicated `U` combinator (or at least used the `Y` combinator right away):

```
const map = f => {
  const mapF = acc => ([head, ...tail]) => head === undefined
    ? acc
    : mapF([...acc, f(head)])(tail);
  return mapF([]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but `U` prevents that `f` have to be passed repeatedly (`h` though) and that a block is needed. Btw, what's the name of such arrows with `{}`?

Comment: As I hinted at, you can use `Y` to do what the declaration of `mapF` does if you cared. But it doesn't really matter, I used this syntax only for a bit of clarity, your original code is just as tail-recursive. Arrows without a concise body are still just arrow functions.

Comment: Oh my gosh, the recursive call is performed when the procedural application of the curried function is finished. I'm such an i... I haven't seen it!